# Flask, проблема с последовательностью параметров в POST запросе

Tags: python, flask

Для проверки подлинности POST запроса необходимо объединить все значения параметров  запроса в строку и получить хеш от нее.
Проблема возникает в том что с помощью Flask я могу только получить параметры в отсортированном виде вследствие чего я не могу получить правильную строку для получения хеша. То есть последовательность параметров в строке теряется. Как получить параметры запроса в правильной последовательности.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод [`request.get_data()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data), он возвращает тело запроса в исходном формате независимо от того какой `content-type`